# How to remove duplicates with out using temporary table in mysql

Tags: sql

How to remove duplicates when we have only one column in Mysql table

If a table is having below rows ..

```
mysql> select * from EMP ;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|   10 |
|   10 |
|   10 |
|   20 |
|   20 |
|   30 |
+------+
```

I need rows after removing duplicates .

```
10
20
30
```

I don't want to use any other temp table . Need a delete query to remove duplicates in mysql

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Select statement is for retrieval purpose . I want duplicate ids to be removed from table

Comment: Do you have any unique column in this table?

Answer (score 1):

Use `distinct`

```
select distinct id from EM
```

You can use `row_number()` to remove duplicates:

```
with todelete as (
      select em.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from em
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: Select statement is for retrieval purpose . I want duplicate ids to be removed from table .

Comment: what is your dbms ?? @Deepthi

Comment: Mysql is my dbms.